# Not receiving output file in my decryption program

Tags: c++, file, iostream, ifstream, decoding

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, but I just haven't been able to figure it out. I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm making a simple decoding program for my own encoding. But for some odd reason, I'm not getting an output. I'm coding in the CodeBlocks IDE and then run it through PowerShell, I've tried running through regular command prompt but this doesn't help. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you very much, Abe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string base64_decode(const std::string &s);
std::string DecryptB64 (std::string s);

const std::string &SALT1 = "hidden";
const std::string &SALT2 = "hidden";
const std::string &SALT3 = "hidden";
const std::string &BASE64_CODES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 3)
        return std::cout << "Programma heeft twee argumenten nodig, input en output!" << std::endl, 2;
    std::string in (argv[1]), out (argv[2]);
    std::ifstream fi (in);
    if(!fi)
        return std::cout << "Kan input bestand '" << in << "' niet lezen!" << std::endl, 3;
    std::string data;
    fi >> data;
    if(!fi)
        return std::cout << "Input bestand '" << in << "' corrupted!" << std::endl, 4;
    data = DecryptB64(data);
    std::ofstream fo (out);
    if (!fo)
        return std::cout << "Kan output bestand '" << out << "' niet lezen!" << std::endl, 5;
    fo << data;
    std::cout << "Decoden is gelukt!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string base64_decode(const std::string &s)
{
        std::string ret;
        std::vector<int> vec(256, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            vec [BASE64_CODES[i]] = i;
        int val = 0, bits = -8;
        for (const auto &c : s)
            {
                if (vec[c] == -1) break;
                val = (val << 6) + vec[c];
                bits += 6;

                if (bits >= 0)
                    {

                        ret.push_back(char((val >> bits) & 0xFF));
                        bits -= 8;
                    }
            }

        return ret;
}

std::string DecryptB64 (std::string s)
{
    s = s.erase (7, 1);
    s = s.erase (1, 1);
    s = base64_decode (s);
    s = s.substr (SALT2.length() + SALT3.length());
    s = s.substr (0, s.length() - SALT1.length());
    s = base64_decode (s);
    s = s.substr (0, s.length() - SALT1.length());
    s = s.erase (7, SALT3.length());
    s = s.substr (SALT1.length());
    s = s.substr (0, s.length() - SALT2.length() - SALT3.length());
    return s;
}
```

Here is the encryption code:

```
#ifndef BASE64_H
#define BASE64_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace Base64
{
    std::string base64_encode(const std::string &);

    const std::string &SALT1 = ":EG:::ZXQL";
    const std::string &SALT2 = ":ZAerPLgfs";
    const std::string &SALT3 = "decrypt696";


    std::string EncryptB64 (std::string s)
    {
        s = SALT1 + s + SALT2 + SALT3;
        s = base64_encode (s);
        return s;
    }

    const std::string &BASE64_CODES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz0123456789+/";

    std::string base64_encode(const std::string &s)
    {
        std::string ret;
        int val = 0;
        int bits = -6;
        const unsigned int b63 = 0x3F;

        for(const auto &c : s)
        {
            val = (val << 8) + c;
            bits += 8;
            while(bits >= 0)
            {
                ret.push_back(BASE64_CODES[(val >> bits) & b63]);
                bits -= 6;
            }
        }

        if(bits > -6)
            ret.push_back(BASE64_CODES[((val << 8) >> (bits+8)) & b63]);

        while(ret.size() % 4)
            ret.push_back('=');

        return ret;
    }
}

#endif // BASE_64
```

And the code that uses the encryption functions:

```
    std::string WriteLog(const T &t)
{
    std::string path = GetPath(true);
    Helper::DateTime dt;
    std::string name = dt.GetDateTimeString("_") + ".log";

    try
    {
        std::ofstream file(path + name);
        if(!file) return "";
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << "[" << dt.GetDateTimeString() << "]" << std::endl << t << std::endl;
        std::string data = Base64::EncryptB64(s.str());
        file << data;
        if(!file)
            return "";
        file.close();
        return name;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Also, here are the contents of an encrypted file to decrypt with the program:

```
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
```

Comment: How are you running your program?  Are you running on the command line or using an IDE?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's impossible to tell whether you're not getting any output because writing fails, or because your decryption is broken, or because of something else.

Comment: works for me, presumably there is some undefined behaviour in `just_some_secret_calculations_for_the_decrypting`

Comment: note that `vec[ c ]` won't work correctly on platforms where characters are signed (most platforms) if `c` is not a 7-bit value. If your output is binary you should open your output stream in binary mode

Comment: Thank you everyone for your response, I've edited the post to add a little more information, so I hope I have cleared up everything.

Comment: We still need a [mcve], what is in the input file? `DecryptB64` has no error checking so is likely to pass invalid indexes to erase which will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: your last 2 `substr` calls in `DecryptB64` don't match `EncryptB64`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've added the contents of a decrypted file as an example and changed the functions so they match. But when I try to decrypt the file, I get these weird characters: LWZ¬Šm’lflVBPkzFOM5zNÓšø

Comment: We still need a [mcve], I think your sample input isn't using the salt values?

Comment: your base64 decoder doesn't produce the correct output

Comment: Ignore that, the base64 output is correct, its probably your `base64_encode` function which is incorrect

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've added the base64_encode function, but I think It's correct though, I've also edited the encrypted file example. But when I try decrypting it I get this error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 7) > this->size() (which is 5)`

Comment: does your input contain non-ascii characters?

Comment: or your salts? We still need a [mcve]

Comment: @AlanBirtles None of it contains non-ascii characters. What's the best way to share the complete example because it's pretty long

Comment: The string you've used to create that input string would probably be enough,I'm reasonably certain other than lack of error checking your decoder works correctly, your base64 encoder doesn't correctly encode non-ascii characters

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've added the function that uses the encryption functions and changed the encrypted example